# creating connection class to use over code base

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I have 2 files. Connect.php and AddUser.php.

I am trying to use the mysqli connection established in connect to insert data to my database from within AddUser. I feel like I have all the pieces in the right place, but it isn't working... Any help would be wonderful!

Here is my code:

***Connect.php***

```
<?php
class Connection
{
    public function connect()
    {
        $conn = "localhost";
        $un = "user";
        $pw = "password";
        $db = "db";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($conn, $un, $pw, $db);

        return $mysqli;
    }
}
```

***AddUser.php***

```
<?php
class addUser{
    public function add() {
        $conn = new Connection();
        $conn->connect();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (user_name) VALUES ('test')";
        $insert = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
```

The connection script is included using a `require_once` statement at the top of my index.php router.

```
<?php
require_once "configs/Toro.php"; //ToroPHP router
require_once "configs/db.cnfg.php"; //db config (where class Connection is written)
require_once "handlers/addUser.php"; //adduser file
```

Comment: try this include_once("connect.php"); in adduser.php

Comment: Let me amend my question, the connection script is included further up the tree before the add user script. Sorry!

Comment: ok,is it showing any errror? can you explain query($sql) function

Comment: Actually, after doing some digging I am getting a 500 Server error because of the ->query function.

The thought behind that was since I have the mysqli connection from Connection->connect() then I should be able to run any available mysqli functions from that.

Comment: So after connecting either you have to use mysqli_query($conn,"$sql"); or if you are using another fuction you have to place this inside that

Comment: I solved this issue for now, but will go back and try yours tomorow! I'll post temporary resolution below...

Answer (score 0):

Temporary resolution was to take Connect() out of the class Connection and have it as a stand a lone function...

```
<?php
    function connect()
    {
        $conn = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === "vagrantup") ? "50.87.147.177" : "localhost";
        $un = "tbremer_bitters";
        $pw = "4t:7*4334S";
        $db = "tbremer_bittersyndrome";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($conn, $un, $pw, $db);

        return $mysqli;
    }
```

This allowed me to use mysqli as an object instead of the PDO version.